# Correctly update state for nested properties

Tags: reactjs

I have following data structure in a component's state. All state properties are controlled components.

```
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
        companyName: '',
        country: '',
        contact: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            phone: ''
        }
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

For instance, 1st level property "Company name" is defined as,

```
<Input label="Company Name" name="companyName" id="companyName" type="text" value={this.state.companyName} onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
```

and 2nd level property "firstName" is defined as,

```
<Input label="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" value={this.state.contact.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
```

My current handleChange(e) method updates state but it adds 2nd level properties to the state. What is the correct way to update the state?

```
    handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [name]: value,
            contact: {
              ...this.state.contact,
              [name]: value,
            }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your state is structured in such a way that it is really hard to do what you would like to do. Perhaps, what you should do is write separate functions. One for first input and second one for updating state on change in second input. Or, you can put firstName, secondName... fields outside contact field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         companyName: '',
         country: '',
         contact: {
             firstName: '',
             lastName: '',
             email: '',
             phone: ''
         }
      };
      // this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); => remove this, you don't need this, bind your functions where you define them using `=>` like I did in the example below
}
```

For your input field

```
<Input label="Company Name" name="companyName" id="companyName" type="text" value={this.state.companyName} onChange={this.handleChange('rootLevel')} required />
```

And for your second level property

```
<Input label="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" value={this.state.contact.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange('contact')} required/>
```

The `onChange` method should go like this

```
handleChange = type => event => {
  if (type === "rootLevel") {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    return;
  }
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [type]: {
      ...this.state[type],
      [name]: value
    }
  });
};
```

As a reference, I have replicated this in Codesandbox, which you can view [[here]](https://codesandbox.io/s/14r76r1234).

Comment: I got the idea, but above handleChange method doesn't compile. 
Failed to compile
./src/components/AddCompanyPage.js
Syntax error: /src/components/AddCompanyPage.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (35:31)

  33 |   }
  34 | 
> 35 |   handleChange = type => event {
     |                                ^
  36 |      if (type === 'rootLevel') {
  37 |         this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  38 |         return;

Comment: Now compilation error has gone away. But it removes previously set values for level 2 properties and updates only current name-value pair. It will work if we change ...[type].prevState, to ...this.state.contact

Comment: I have updated my `handleChange` method. Now it is working. Kindly mark this as the accepted answer. If it works.

Comment: Yes it is working and most suitable when there are multiple hierarchical or nested data model

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused because you add `[name]: value` twice. So if you update the first level property, you also add a second level property and vice-versa.

I would suggest you to make the state completely flat. That way you can keep using the same `handleChange` method.

```
state = {
   companyName: '',
    country: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
};
```

otherwise, you have to tell in your `handleChange` method in which level you want to update the property. something like:

```
handleChange(event, level) {
   if (level === 1) { // or whatever way you think is best to get the right level
       this.setState({
           ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value
       });
   } else {
       this.setState({
           ...this.state, 
           content: {
               ...this.state.contact,
               [event.target.name]: event.target.value
           }
       });
   }
}
```

your input would look like this:

```
<Input label="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" value={this.state.contact.firstName} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 2)} required/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sort of hierarchical state is used to submit state directly to backend (with JSON.stringify(this.state)). without reconstructing the object.

Comment: Alright. Then you can have something like the send part, telling the `handleChange` method which part of the state you should update. Does that work for you?

Comment: I updated my answer with how the `<input>` would look like for the send option.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[name]` for both the first and second level hash.
As a result if you edit, say `firstName`, it would add `firstName` to the first level as well.
Try this.

```
handleChange(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  if(['companyName', 'country'].includes(name)){
    this.setState( prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    });
  }else{
    this.setState( prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      contact: {
        ...prevState.contact,
        [name]: value,
      }
   });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since some people have already given some solutions.
Let's think about a solution that works with a few numbers of lines.

```
handleChange(e) {
let contact = this.state.contact;
    if (contact.hasOwnProperty(e.target.name)) {
        contact[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }); 
}
```

This solution works. I think you should not overcomplicate things like this and should just keep the state flat and should just reformat while sending the data.